# Proving set equality

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of functions, then I am having hard time trying to see why

$$ \{ x : ( \max_{n \leq k} f_n) (x) > a \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{k} \{ x : f_n(x) > a \} $$

these two sets are equal. Can someone help me see this please? thanks

Comment: Don't you mean $\max \limits_{n\leq k}\left(f_n(x)\right)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the definition of $\max_{n\le k}f_n$:

$$\left(\max_{n\le k}f_n\right)(x)=\max_{n\le k}f_n(x)\;,$$

so $\left(\max_{n\le k}f_n\right)(x)>a$ if and only if $\max_{n\le k}f_n(x)>a$, which is true if and only if $f_n(x)>a$ for some $n\le k$, i.e., if and only if $x\in\{y:f_n(y)>a\}$ for some $n\le k$. Finally, $x\in\{y:f_n(y)>a\}$ for some $n\le k$ if and only if $x\in\bigcup\{y:f_n(y)>a\}$.

Comment: Nice answer. But in the first line after the equation, the second $\max$ should be $\max_{n\leq k}$ rather than $\max_{n\leq x}$, right?

Comment: @hejseb: It should indeed. Fixed now; thanks!

Comment: I don't get it. In order to talk about $\max \limits_{n\leq k}f_n$ you need an order on the set $\{f_1,\ldots , f_k\}$. What order is that?

Comment: @GitGud: You don’t need an order on the set of functions. The displayed line in my answer is the **definition** of the function $\max_{n\le k}f_n$.

Comment: I see now. I disagree with using this notation, though. The symbol $\max \limits_{n\leq k}f_n$is already reserved to mean $\max \left(\{f_n\colon n\leq k\}\right)$ if such a $\max$ exists. **Edit:** By the way, \$\max \limits_{n\leq k}\$ will get you the $n\leq k$ below the $\max$.

Comment: @GitGud: This is a perfectly standard notation; another that I’ve seen is $\bigvee_{n\le k}f_n$. In context the two meanings are very rarely in conflict, so there’s no real problem.